# jQuery active menu item

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a kind of drop down menu: http://jsfiddle.net/hu5x3hL1/1/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu" class="sidebar">
    <li> <a href="#" class="clickme">Click me 1</a>

        <ul id="menu1" style="display:none">
            <li><a class="dropdown-class-name" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-class-name" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="clickme">Click me 2</a>

        <ul style="display:none">
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#menu li > a').click(function (e) {

        if ($(this).next('ul').length > 0) {

            var subNav = $(this).next('ul');

            if (subNav.is(':visible')) {
                subNav.slideUp('normal')
            } else {
                $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                subNav.slideDown('normal');
            }
        }
    });
});

$('#menu1 li a').click(function (e) {
    $('a').removeClass('dropdown-class-name wrapper');
    $(this).addClass('dropdown-class-name wrapper');
});
```

**CSS**

```
#menu1 li a.wrapper {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

You can see that the active menu item is highlighted in bold. But on my web-site when I click some drop down link, the new page is opening, but active menu item already isn't bold. How to keep it highlighted in bold on the new page of the web-site?

Comment: use ajax or look at ten http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/more-css-tricks.shtml

Comment: How to use ajax? What should I do?

Comment: hmm you gotta google bwoy

Comment: If I could google it I wouldn't ask the question here

Comment: try this http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use php, and the url is like www.site.com/?page=home, you will use $_GET

```
    ..
    <li>
     <a href="?page=<?=$ifen.$arNewItem[1]?>" <?=($_GET['page'] == $ifen.$arNewItem[1]) ? 'class="active"' : null ?>>Home</a>
    </li>
    ..
```

Comment: Yes, I use php, but I get the links in a loop from the array `<?=$ifen.$arNewItem[1]?>`

Comment: Use the same way: if $_GET['pagee'] == $ifen.$arNewItem[1]
If array[1] is 'Home' link, for example

Comment: I used this: `<a href="<?=$ifen.$arNewItem[1]?>" <?=($_GET['page'] == '$ifen.$arNewItem[1]') ? 'class="active"' : null ?> class="dropdown-class-name">...</a>` but it's doesn't work

Comment: `<a href="<?=$ifen.$arNewItem[1]?>" <?=($_GET['page'] == $ifen.$arNewItem[1]) ? 'class="active"' : null ?> class="dropdown-class-name">...</a>`
Without quote for the array.
I just update the code above